# Eclipse update the workspace with new Classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm working on a web application developed using Play framework. I'm using sbteclipse plugin to generate the eclipse related files. The problem I'm facing is whenever I add a new dependency in the .sbt file it does not get reflected in the Eclipse project automatically. What can I do so that the new added dependency gets reflected in the Eclipse project automatically?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the workspace? Select all projects in the workspace and right click -> Refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `play eclipse` (for play 2.3 it is `activator eclipse`) again and refresh the project. It solves the problem for me.